# Not able to update ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, adt

I get this error while installing the previous version.

> An error occurred while uninstalling
>       session context was:(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall, operand=[R]org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86 1.0.0.I20120608-1200 --> null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).
>
> Backup of file D:\ADT\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\eclipse\eclipse.exe failed.
>   Can not remove : D:\ADT\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\eclipse\eclipse.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the answers provided related to this issue solved my problem.
Eventually, I downloaded latest **Android Studio** and installed it. So far, extremely happy with its performance and features. I would recommend to install Android Studio.

Comment: i also installed android studio, but still i like to use eclipse as well. did you find a solution?

Comment: @alex - No, I am happy with Android Studio. Getting almost everything under one roof (whatever I used to do with Eclipse).

Answer (score 0):

> Help-->Install New Software-->What is already installed?
>
> Then, Select "Android DDMS, Andoid Devlopment Tools,Android Hierarcy
>   Viewer, Android native Development Tools, Android Traceview, Tracer
>   for OpenGL ES" and click Uninstall.
>
> After all this step, try Add link
>   ([https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/][1]) and name is ADT
>   Plugin. This link will get the latest ADT Plugin. In this way you
>   reinstall the ADT.

Comment: Even if i select all the packages mentioned above, the uninstall button is not getting enabled.

Comment: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  Software being installed: Android DDMS 23.0.6.1720515 (com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms.feature.feature.group 23.0.6.1720515)
  Software currently installed: Android Developer Tools 21.1.0.201302060051 (com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product 21.1.0.201302060051)

Comment: @HussainChachuliya did you find a solution i am having the same issue

Answer (score 0):

You need a new clean Eclipse version. And then install ADT plugin.
It seems like adt update doesn't work

Eclipse
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/mars/R/eclipse-java-mars-R-win32-x86_64.zip&mirror_id=576

ADT Plugin
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/

ADT SDK: the last one